# Flurry Analytics access in China

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics, great-firewall-of-china

We all know that Google and Google Analytics are blocked from app users in China. But how about flurry? Can i collect analytics data from my Mobile iOS and Android App users living in China?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flurry Analytics does work in China, on both iOS and Android.